# Change frame of UITableView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView connected through delegate like that:

[image]

Everything work fine. But i need to change height of UITableView dynamically, based on content of other UI elements. Following doesnt work:

```
/* UITableView Frame */



 CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 200);
    self.spotlightTableView.frame = newFrame;
```

Its always use frames, that i set in StoryBoard. How to fix that?

Comment: y do u have tableview in a scrollview ? do u want to keep any other view in scrollview other than table view ?

Comment: where did u call the code ? in view did load ?

Comment: After notification in view did load. Yes i want to keep it all in scroll view.

Comment: in view did load, the table view frame is not yet set, u need to do it in view will appear atleast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should set the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. You can also do it in `viewWillAppear` but you should note that `viewDidLayout` is called every time a layout occurs (e.g. device rotation) while `viewWillAppear` is not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did this in `viewWillAppear ` but every time I triggered the In-call status bar, it changed back to the container view size. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` works well.

Answer (score 0):

Where in your code do you set this new frame ?

Anyway, you should **really** be using [autolayout / contraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) to dynamically adapt your table view frame based on other UI elements.